# Issue with opencv dnn modules on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I'm trying to run an opencv program with CodeBlocks on Ubuntu. I successfully built opencv with opencv_contrib but for some reason my dnn modules aren't working correctly when trying to build the program itself.

Guide I used to install opencv:
https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2016/08/27/install-and-configure-opencv-in-code-blocks/
Note: I configured my cmake to properly work with dnn. Configuration
specifications included in picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml9ke.jpg
What I've tried:
Uninstalling and reinstalling opencv.
I ran pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv to check if dnn was mentioned. opencv_dnn was included, but strangely opencv_saliency was included as well, even though I unchecked it in cmake.

*Build log from trying to run program is below.*

```html
-------------- Build: Debug in FBT (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -c /home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/FBT-Code-master/main.o
In file included from /home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/main.cpp:5:0:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp: In member function ‘void detectionModel::runModel(cv::Mat&, std::vector<player>&, std::vector<foundBox>&)’:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:13:67: error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘double’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘cv::Mat cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::blobFromImage(const cv::Mat&, double, const Size&, const Scalar&, bool, bool)’
     blobFromImage(frame, blob, 1.0, inpSize, Scalar(), true, false);
                                                                   ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:16:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::forward(std::vector<cv::Mat>&, const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’
     net.forward(outs, outNames);
                               ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn.hpp:62:0,
                 from /home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:4,
                 from /home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:396:21: note: candidate: cv::Mat cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::forward(const cv::String&)
         CV_WRAP Mat forward(const String& outputName = String());
                     ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:396:21: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:403:22: note: candidate: void cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::forward(std::vector<cv::Mat>&, const cv::String&)
         CV_WRAP void forward(std::vector<Mat>& outputBlobs, const String& outputName = String());
                      ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:403:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘const cv::String&’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:409:22: note: candidate: void cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::forward(std::vector<cv::Mat>&, const std::vector<cv::String>&)
         CV_WRAP void forward(std::vector<Mat>& outputBlobs,
                      ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:409:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘const std::vector<cv::String>&’
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:416:22: note: candidate: void cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v2::Net::forward(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat> >&, const std::vector<cv::String>&)
         CV_WRAP void forward(std::vector<std::vector<Mat> >& outputBlobs,
                      ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.hpp:416:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<cv::Mat>’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat> >&’
In file included from /home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/main.cpp:5:0:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:50:70: error: ‘NMSBoxes’ was not declared in this scope
     NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold, indices);
                                                                      ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp: In member function ‘bool tracker::add(cv::Mat&, std::vector<foundBox>&)’:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:130:70: error: ‘NMSBoxes’ was not declared in this scope
     NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold, indices);
                                                                      ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:140:22: error: ‘TrackerCSRT’ has not been declared
         fb.tracker = TrackerCSRT::create();
                      ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp: In member function ‘bool tracker::add(cv::Mat&, std::vector<player>&)’:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:171:70: error: ‘NMSBoxes’ was not declared in this scope
     NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold, indices);
                                                                      ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:181:21: error: ‘TrackerCSRT’ has not been declared
         p.tracker = TrackerCSRT::create();
                     ^
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp: In member function ‘bool tracker::add(cv::Mat&, std::vector<player>&, std::vector<foundBox>&)’:
/home/nurc/Desktop/FBT-Code-master/detect_track.hpp:212:70: error: ‘NMSBoxes’ was not declared in this scope
     NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold, indices);
                                                                      ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

Comment: Have you built it with opencv_contrib?

Comment: Can you share cmake list which you used while building opencv ? Can you share the code snippet which giving this error ? Can you share the command how you tried to compile your program ?

Comment: @yuRa I did build it with opencv_contrib

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I can share the cmakelist, but cannot share the code snippet. To compile the program i just clicked build in codeblocks.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk CMakeLists.txt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z1hhwBWiMPE2wrRZyQDBaYYvvocsFmRq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It could be the code as well so I would recommend sharing it

Comment: For reasons involving my university I'm not allowed to share it. The header has #include opencv2/dnn.pp and the code works on another person's laptop with my configurations, he is using windows and im using ubuntu

Comment: Are you by any chance using DNN for reading a models weight and config path?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm using DNN for, why?